# Traer datos de varias tablas diferentes, en base a varias condiciones en cada tabla, SQL, MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

El problema me resulta en que quiero obtener los datos de tres tablas diferentes, en base a dos condiciones, estas dos condiciones estan dadas en dos diferentes tablas... en MYSQL

Quiero traer de las tablas estas columnas:

- `Customers` (clientes), y la columna `name`,
- `Order` (ordenes), y la columna `date`,
- `Sales` (ventas), y la columna `total`.

Las relaciones se componen de, los clientes tienen las ordenes (1:N) y las ordenes tienen varias ventas (N:1) (por que se contabilizan por cantidad de producto)

Pero las filas deben estar de acuerdo a estas 2 condiciones:

- Que `date` sea 2015.
- Que `total` sea el maximo.

Logro hacerlo de la manera siguiente, pero me parece que no es correcta la manera, por que al final solo estoy cortando la tabla, ademas que me parece muy sucia y verbosa la query, a demas, tambien aplicar este metodo a mas tablas no me serviria, y tambien quisiera saber si es posible anidar dos condiciones o mas en tablas de sql y de que forma hacerlo...

```sql
select 
    c.name as Customer, 
    o.id as Order_ID, 
    year(o.date) as Order_Year, 
    o.date as Order_Date, 
    s.total as Max_Sale 
from customers as c 
    inner join orders as o on(o.customer_id=c.id)
    inner join sales as s on(s.order_id=o.id)
where year(o.date) = 2015
order by s.total desc limit 1;
```

Comment: ¿Y cómo están relacionadas esas tablas? ¿Por qué campos las combinas? ¿Podrías añadir el SQL con el que generar las tablas, insertar unos datos de ejemplo y el resultado que esperas para esa muestra?

Answer (score 1):

Ya estoy super oxidado en SQL, pero puedes intentar crear una view, que agrupe por año y sacar el valor maximo del total, y luego usar `any_value` para no tener que meter todo a la clausula group by:

```
-- Creamos nuestra view
create view max_sales_per_year AS
select 
    any_value(o.id) as id
    ,any_value(o.customer_id) as customer_id
    ,year(o.date) as year
    ,any_value(s.order_id) as order_id
    ,MAX(s.total) as max_sale
from sales s
join orders o 
    on s.order_id = o.id
group by year(o.date)
;

-- Usamos nuestra view
-- Esta es nuestra query final
select
    c.name as Customer,
    s.year as Order_Year,
    s.max_sale as Max_Sale
from customers as c
join orders as o
    on o.customer_id=c.id
join max_sales_per_year as s
    on s.order_id=o.id
where year(o.date) = 2015
;
```

Entonces si tenemos los valores:

```
insert into customers
values 
(1, "uno"),
(2, "dos"),
(3, "tres");

insert into orders
values
(1, 1, "2015-02-02"),
(2, 1, "2015-02-02"),
(3, 2, "2015-02-02"),
(4, 2, "2015-02-02"),
(5, 3, "2015-02-02"),
(6, 3, "2015-02-02");

insert into sales
values
(1, 1),
(2, 2),
(3, 1),
(4, 3),
(5, 1),
(6, 4);
```

Al correr nuestra query, tendremos como resultado:

```
mysql> select
    ->     c.name as Customer,
    ->     s.year as Order_Year,
    ->     s.max_sale as Max_Sale
    -> from customers as c
    -> join orders as o
    ->     on o.customer_id=c.id
    -> join max_sales_per_year as s
    ->     on s.order_id=o.id
    -> where year(o.date) = 2015
    -> ;
+----------+------------+----------+
| Customer | Order_Year | Max_Sale |
+----------+------------+----------+
| uno      |       2015 |        4 |
+----------+------------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: me quda la duda de para que sirve el any_value, sin embargo lo que me pasa es que me trae todos los sales uno por uno, mas no me trae el maximo, tal vez seria util saber si puedo crear una `tabla virtual` y hacer una consulta sobre esa tabla.

Comment: Según entiendo, con group by y max deberían traerte solo uno y ese tendría que ser el máximo. Quizás será por el tipo de dato que tiene "s.total"? Es INT o VARCHAR?

Comment: No, lo lamento, lo que trae es el primer nombre de la lista de 2015, mas no el nombre del maximo, y la verdad se el nombre del maximo, por que en una tabla desnormalizada en pandas, se cual es es maximo de ventas